# calling a member function of a class by member function of another class?

Tags: c++, member, func

i have two classes A & B.i want to call a member function of A by member function of B.

```
class A {
   public:
      void memberofa();
}
```

class b:

```
 class B {
  public:
    void memberofb();
}
```

now i need to call memberofa from inside memberofb.
Any suggestions and syntaxes will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class A {
   public:
      A() {};
      void memberofa()
      {
        //you cant make object of B here because compiler doesn't see B yet
        //if you do want to make Object of B here, define this function somewhere
        //after definition of B class
        printf("printing from member of A\n");
      };
};

class B {
   public:
      B() {};
      void memberofb()
      {
        printf("printing from member of B\n");
        A objA;
        objA.memberofa();
      };
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    b.memberofb();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. B inherit from A
2. B contain A object
3. A::memberofa is static function
4. A is singleton class
5. A inherit from B, B has memberofa and it is virtual function.

Comment: Expanding this answer into a full (albeit pseudo-) code example would really help readability!